# Why do I get "authentication" errors on this "Open" configuration?

Tags: networking, wifi, dhcp, interface, hostapd

I have the following `ifcfg-wlan0` file:

```
DEVICE=wlan0
BOOTPROTO=none
ONBOOT=yes
IPADDR=192.168.5.1
NETMASK=255.255.255.0
NETWORK=192.168.5.0
NAME=wlan0
USERCTL=no
```

the following `dhcpd.conf` file:

```
DHCPDARGS=wlan0;
default-lease-time 600;
max-lease-time 7200;
authoritative;

subnet 192.168.5.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
  range 192.168.5.10 192.168.5.200;
}
```

the following `hostapd.conf` file:

```
ctrl_interface=/var/run/hostapd
ctrl_interface_group=wheel

macaddr_acl=0
auth_algs=1
ignore_broadcast_ssid=0

driver=nl80211
interface=wlan0
hw_mode=g
channel=1
ssid=HOTSPOT
```

The SSID:HOTSPOT shows up on my device as 'Open' but when it tries to connect I get "authentication error". I've tried from several devices, with the same results.  It seems on the surface that it is a hostapd config problem. Is it possible it is a problem with my dhcpd or my interface config?